# when zooming the page the alignment of div boxes changes and collides

Tags: html, css

I created two `div` boxes inside the container class. When zooming the page in and out, the alignment of the div boxes gets changed and collide with each other. I attached my HTML and CSS. I need the `div` boxes to be fixed inside the container class while zooming in and out. I am stuck here. Any help please?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type = "text/css">
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
body{
    background-color:#e1e3e4;
    }
.main{
    width:90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
header{
    height:160px;
    background-color:#3c948b;
    }
.container{
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    min-height:500px;

    }
.content{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    border: 2px solid #111;
    width:70%;
    }
.panel{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    top:10px;
    left:20px;
    border: 2px solid #111;
    width:330px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
    <header>
        <h1>My personal blog</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            #content
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            #panel
        </div>

   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about removing the floats and doing it with a `display: table`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type = "text/css">
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body{
    background-color:#e1e3e4;
}
.main{
    width:90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header{
    height:160px;
    background-color:#3c948b;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    min-height:500px;
}
.content{
    display: table-cell;
    top:10px;
    border: 2px solid #111;
    width:70%;
}
.panel{
    display: table-cell;
    top:10px;
    border: 2px solid #111;
    width:330px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
 <header>
     <h1>My personal blog</h1>
 </header>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="content">
   #content
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
   #panel
  </div>
  
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah it works. Very thank you  @PiotrZientara and all.

Answer (score 2):

With your `#content` occupying 70% of the current window width, there is only 30% for `#panel`. But it has a fixed width of 330px, so with a window less than about 1000px it cannot fit side-by-side. Additionally, borders, paddings and so on use room, so the required minimum window width is even larger.

Use relative widths for both elements (70% / 30%) and set [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) style to calculate actual widths to include the padding and border (`border-box`).

Comment: Thank you for replying me sir.. I am a newbie here. Can u please explain me with the example code for better understanding? @JoachimSchirrmacher